# all possible combinations in the list

Tags: r, dataframe

my data frame:

```
data <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L,1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), col1 = c(9, 
9.05, 7.15, 7.21, 7.34, 8.12, 7.5, 7.84, 7.8, 7.52, 8.84, 6.98, 
6.1, 6.89, 6.5, 7.5, 7.8, 5.5, 6.61, 7.65, 7.68,8.0,9.0), col2 = c(11L, 
11L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L,3L,4L), col3 = c(7L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 
5L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 2L,5L,6L), 
    col4 = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 
    11L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 11L,13L,12L), col5 = c(11L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 
    8L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 9L,4L,5L)), .Names = c("group", "col1", 
"col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

function:

```
comb <- list(c(2, 4), c(3, 5), c(4, 6))

test.fun <- function(dat) { 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(comb, function(x) {
    SUM <- dat[[x[1]]]+dat[[x[2]]]
    data.frame(NAME = sprintf('Group %s by Group %s', x[1], x[2]),
                SUM)
   
  }))
}

result <- purrr::map_df(split(data, data$group), test.fun, .id = 'Group')
```

Now this function processes 2 columns of list in the `list(c(2, 4), c(3, 5), c(4, 6))`. I want it to process any amount for example:

```
list(c(2, 4, 6), c(3, 5, 6), c(3, 4, 6), c(2, 3), c(3, 5))
```

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: What I meant is that `comb` is defined outside. and it is not an input to the function 'test.fun`

Answer (score 2):

May be this helps

```
test.fun <- function(dat, comb) { 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(comb, function(x) {
    SUM <- rowSums(dat[x], na.rm = TRUE)
    data.frame(NAME = paste0("Group ", toString(x)),
                SUM)
   
  }))
}
```

-testing

```
comb2 <- list(c(2, 4, 6), c(3, 5, 6), c(3, 4, 6), c(2, 3), c(3, 5))

purrr::map_df(split(data, data$group), test.fun, comb = comb2, .id = 'Group') %>%
    as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 115 × 3
   Group NAME            SUM
   <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
 1 1     Group 2, 4, 6  27  
 2 1     Group 2, 4, 6  21.0
 3 1     Group 2, 4, 6  12.2
 4 1     Group 2, 4, 6  16.2
 5 1     Group 2, 4, 6  29.3
 6 1     Group 2, 4, 6  21.1
 7 1     Group 2, 4, 6  19.5
 8 1     Group 2, 4, 6  22.8
 9 1     Group 3, 5, 6  33  
10 1     Group 3, 5, 6  23  
# … with 105 more rows
```

---

For pairwise, use `combn`

```
 bind_rows(lapply(comb2, function(x) {
   SUM <- combn(x, 2, FUN = function(y) rowSums(data[y], 
          na.rm = TRUE))
   nm1 <- rep(combn(x, 2, FUN = paste, collapse="_"), 
       each = nrow(data))
   data.frame(NAME= nm1, SUM)}))
```

Comment: The total amount is clear. And if I want to make a pairwise sum. Example 2-4, 2-6, 4-6, etc.

Comment: @GOGAGOGA Please check the update

Comment: Not really, initially my function counts the sum of two numbers in pairs, in order not to prescribe all combinations in pairs, I wanted not to prescribe all combinations in two, but to specify them in the list as c(2, 4, 6), in order not to enter list(with(2,4), with(2,6), with (4,6)). Maybe we misunderstood each other

Comment: @GOGAGOGA I meant to check the update in my post

Comment: I used `combn` which does exactly what you meant in the comment.

Comment: @GOGAGOGA I am also thinking that either your description or your input `list` is incorrect because you mentioned `all possible combinations in the list` and then you showed `comb <- list(c(2, 4), c(3, 5), c(4, 6))`. In the strict sense your test.fun is not doing the all possible combinations of the elements of the `list`

Answer (score 1):

A way with `outer` that avoids expensive `split`ting of the data. The `SUM` is achieved using `rowSums` on a subset derived in a `Vectorize`d `FUN`ction. I used different data with more groups,

```
groupFun <- function(data, comb2) {
  FUN <- Vectorize(function(x, y) rowSums(data[data$group == x, y]), SIMPLIFY=F)
  o <- outer(unique(data$group), comb2, FUN)
  res <- cbind(
    expand.grid(
      Group=as.character(data$group), 
      NAME=sapply(comb2, function(x) sprintf('Group %s by Group %s', x[1], x[2])),
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
    SUM=unlist(o))
  res <- res[order(res$Group), ]  ## optional
  return(res)
}
```

where:

```
all.equal(purrr::map_df(split(data, data$group), test.fun, .id = 'Group'),
          `rownames<-`(groupFun(data, comb), NULL))
# [1] TRUE
```

### Result

```
comb2 <- list(c(2, 4, 6), c(3, 5, 6), c(3, 4, 6), c(2, 3), c(3, 5))

groupFun(data, comb2)
#    Group               NAME   SUM
# 1      1 Group 2 by Group 4 16.56
# 2      1 Group 2 by Group 4 13.26
# 13     1 Group 3 by Group 5 14.00
# 14     1 Group 3 by Group 5 12.00
# 25     1 Group 3 by Group 4 22.00
# 26     1 Group 3 by Group 4 14.00
# 37     1 Group 2 by Group 3 12.56
# 38     1 Group 2 by Group 3  7.26
# 49     1 Group 3 by Group 5 11.00
# 50     1 Group 3 by Group 5  9.00
# 3      2 Group 2 by Group 4 17.84
# 4      2 Group 2 by Group 4 24.43
# 15     2 Group 3 by Group 5 14.00
# 16     2 Group 3 by Group 5 10.00
# 27     2 Group 3 by Group 4 14.00
# 28     2 Group 3 by Group 4 17.00
# 39     2 Group 2 by Group 3 13.84
# 40     2 Group 2 by Group 3 11.43
# 51     2 Group 3 by Group 5 10.00
# 52     2 Group 3 by Group 5  4.00
# 5      3 Group 2 by Group 4 24.10
# 6      3 Group 2 by Group 4 17.02
# 17     3 Group 3 by Group 5 26.00
# 18     3 Group 3 by Group 5 22.00
# 29     3 Group 3 by Group 4 23.00
# 30     3 Group 3 by Group 4 21.00
# 41     3 Group 2 by Group 3 15.10
# 42     3 Group 2 by Group 3 14.02
# 53     3 Group 3 by Group 5 15.00
# 54     3 Group 3 by Group 5 12.00
# 7      4 Group 2 by Group 4 20.97
# 8      4 Group 2 by Group 4 22.87
# 19     4 Group 3 by Group 5 24.00
# 20     4 Group 3 by Group 5 11.00
# 31     4 Group 3 by Group 4 25.00
# 32     4 Group 3 by Group 4 19.00
# 43     4 Group 2 by Group 3 11.97
# 44     4 Group 2 by Group 3 13.87
# 55     4 Group 3 by Group 5 18.00
# 56     4 Group 3 by Group 5  7.00
# 9      5 Group 2 by Group 4 25.45
# 10     5 Group 2 by Group 4 21.83
# 21     5 Group 3 by Group 5 22.00
# 22     5 Group 3 by Group 5 22.00
# 33     5 Group 3 by Group 4 25.00
# 34     5 Group 3 by Group 4 20.00
# 45     5 Group 2 by Group 3 20.45
# 46     5 Group 2 by Group 3 19.83
# 57     5 Group 3 by Group 5 16.00
# 58     5 Group 3 by Group 5 14.00
# 11     6 Group 2 by Group 4 14.89
# 12     6 Group 2 by Group 4 25.77
# 23     6 Group 3 by Group 5 22.00
# 24     6 Group 3 by Group 5 18.00
# 35     6 Group 3 by Group 4 20.00
# 36     6 Group 3 by Group 4 20.00
# 47     6 Group 2 by Group 3 14.89
# 48     6 Group 2 by Group 3 15.77
# 59     6 Group 3 by Group 5 17.00
# 60     6 Group 3 by Group 5 12.00
```

### Benchmark

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
# purrr 7.067411 7.173874 7.887650 7.253130 8.325982 17.341812   100   b
# outer 3.233047 3.296393 3.499889 3.366309 3.466582  5.976934   100  a
```

More than twice as fast.

---

*Data*

```
data <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L), col1 = c(2.13, 8.91, 8.72, 1.26, 10.7, 1.23, 2.05, 
2.77, 9.35, 8.82, 8.41, 1.1), col2 = c(4, 8, 9, 1, 11, 6, 6, 
11, 1, 7, 9, 1), col3 = c(10, 2, 9, 7, 10, 7, 4, 10, 4, 10, 11, 
1), col4 = c(5, 6, 8, 7, 2, 6, 10, 4, 10, 3, 4, 10), col5 = c(4, 
8, 9, 4, 1, 9, 7, 7, 7, 8, 2, 9)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In your function outputs only 2-4 variants from c(2, 4, 6), but it does not output 2-6 and 4-6